# Передать два значение в Ajax на сервер

Tags: jquery, ajax

Есть Ajax который должен передавать два значения. Сделал только со одним.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "/ajax/search_bid_country",
    data: "city_from="+city_from,
    success: function(answer) {
        $(".result_article").empty();
        $(".result_article").append(answer);
        $(".result_article").fadeIn();
        $(".load").css({display:"none"});
    }
});
```

Но вот второй не могу передать пишит ошибку,

```
data: "city_from="+city_from, "city_whre="+city_where,
```

Как быть

Comment: `data: {city_from:city_from,city_where:city_where}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

все просто

```
data: "city_from=" + city_from + "&city_whre=" + city_where,
```

теперь должно сработать

Comment: Спасибо работает

Comment: был рад помочь! =)

Answer (score 3):

Конечно будет ошибка, запятая в вашем примере означает переход к другому свойству объекта. Вам нужно в свойство `data` указать сериализованную строку или объект. Об этом четко написанно в [документации](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

В вашем случае просто вместо запятой использовать конкатенацию:

```
data: "city_from=" + city_from + "&city_where=" + city_where,
```

Либо лучше передать объект:

```
data: {city_from: city_from, city_where: city_where},
```

Но что будет когда параметров станет ещё больше? Будет много ненужной писанины. Используйте лучше [функцию сериализации](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

```
data: $("form").serialize(),
```

Comment: Ставлю Плюс так как ответ уже принл, про сериализацию не знал

Comment: @duddeniska вы можете изменить принятие ответа, если что